# Is it possible to get the current dialog step name?

Tags: c#, botframework

I am writing a bot and I want to create a step by step help system.  I setup a dictionary that allow each dialog to overwrite the help text for each step in it:

```
public abstract class BaseDialog : ComponentDialog
{
    private static Dictionary<string, string> StepHelp = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    protected static void AddStepHelp(string function, string text)
    {
        StepHelp.Add(function, text);
    }
    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> InterruptAsync(DialogContext innerDc, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Activity helpMessage;
        string curStepName = ""; //???
        if (userText == "help" && StepHelp.ContainsKey(curStepName))
        {
            helpMessage = MessageFactory.Text(StepHelp[curStepName], StepHelp[curStepName], InputHints.ExpectingInput);
        }
        await innerDc.Context.SendActivityAsync(helpMessage, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Then I add the text in the chidl dialog:

```
public class MyChildDialog: BaseDialog
{
    static MyChildDialog()
    {
        AddStepHelp(nameof(Step1), "Help text for step1");
    }
    public MyChildDialog()
    {
        AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(nameof(WaterfallDialog), new WaterfallStep[]
        {
            Step1
        }));
        InitialDialogId = nameof(WaterfallDialog);
    }
    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> Step1(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

    }
}
```

You can see in the InterruptAsync function above that I call the dictionary to get the help message in the base dialog, but how do I get the current step name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the current step *index* as well as the dialog name, so you should be able to create a unique identifier from that information (as long as you didn't name all the dialogs "waterfallDialog" from the example like I did!). I'm using node but I'm assuming getting the data from your stepContext is similar or the same.

- The dialog name can be found at `stepContext.stack[stepContext.stack.length-1].id`.
- The step index can be found at `stepContext.stack[stepContext.stack.length-1].state.stepIndex`.

I can't recall if you can end up with nested dialogs inside a waterfall dialog. I know your main/outer context will have the whole stack, but I *think* you'll always just have the one element inside your particular waterfall. That said, the current dialog should be the last one the stack, so accessing it as `stepContext.stack.length-1` should work in either case. In the event the current dialog is at element 0, obviously you could just access it as such.

So long as your waterfall dialog names are unique, you'd end up with identifiers like waterfallDialog0, waterfallDialog1, etc. that you could then map in your dictionary to help texts.

It occurred to me you might be trying to access this from outside the waterfall dialog. In that case you should still be able to get that from your outer dialog context. You would likely have to use a recursive function to get it, something like

```js
getInnermostActiveDialog(dc) {
    var child = dc.child;

    return child ? this.getInnermostActiveDialog(child) : dc.activeDialog;
}
```

where `dc` is your outer dialog context. I haven't gone this deep into things but you should then be able to get the same `id` and `stepIndex` values.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the help.  I converted your code to C#.  This solution is workable although I guess there is no way to actually get the step name?  Using step number is workable but not elegant.

Comment: I'm not aware of a way. It may be possible but you'd have to get the name of the function, and I think that would only work if you are inside the function when you need the step name. I've never tried that before but there seem to be some articles out there on getting the currently executing function name if you want to try that.

Answer (score 1):

While it's easy to get the step index as billoverton explained, getting the step name is difficult. The [`_steps`](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs/WaterfallDialog.cs#L24) field is private and so is [the method that returns the step name](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs/WaterfallDialog.cs#L207-L220) so you won't be able to access the steps even if your class derives from `WaterfallDialog`. The step names are only exposed through the telemetry client so you might consider writing a custom telemetry client that somehow exposes the information to your bot but at that point it's probably easier just to use reflection to access the private members.

Since you only really want the step name to use as a key for your dictionary, just using the step index instead is a much better option. You could use a `Dictionary<int, string>` but it makes sense to use a `List<string>` if you intend to have a help string for every step in the waterfall.

Comment: Unfortunately this seem to be the best we can do but okay.

Comment: What do you mean? Are you saying you have to use a `Dictionary<string, string>`? Why?

Comment: Basically, I want to be able to access the current step name giving the dialogContext and as you say it's not possible, so the best I can do is use step ID to identify which step I am currently on.  The dictionary is just my internal implementation to get the help string, either that using the step ID as key or using the step name as key.  That part does not change.

Comment: It sounds like you don't actually need the step name, so what's so unfortunate about that?